# How to make a class with static members and function thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class defined as:

```
class Artifacts {
    private static boolean isThreadStarted = false;
    private SomeClass someClass;
    public static void startThread() {
        isThreadStarted = true;
    }
    public static void setSomeClass(SomeClass = someClass1) {
       if(isThreadStarted) {
           someClass = someClass1;
       }
    }
    public static SomeClass getSomeClass() {
        return someClass;
    }
}
```

Now the use case is that a method will make the value of isThreadStarted to be true. After that, a thread will start and using the value of someClass.There can be multiple threads setting and getting the value of someClass. I want to make this thread safe.

There is an annotation `@ThreadSafe` and there is a function `synchronized static` which I guess will do the thing. Please help in deciding the right approach.

Comment: you need to synchronize those methods

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you want. Making all methods `synchronized` does not guarantee thread safety.

Comment: You also need to make your code correct. What you posted is not valid Java code.

Comment: Why is all that static necessary?

Comment: Don't mind the compile errors. Just tell the logic.

Comment: The zen of concurrent programming is to think not in terms of methods and variables but in terms of mutable state and state transitions.  Can you describe the state space of your class?  The more difficult its transitions are to reason about (or the more vague) the harder it will be to achieve real thread safety.  Really, the simplest thing you can do is make your class immutable ... because thread safety becomes baked in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Life_Hacker,

## 1st way

use **static synchronized** keyword with function to make Class Level lock in multithreading environment.

example :

```
public static synchronized void setSomeClass(Artifacts.class) {
   if(isThreadStarted) {
       someClass = someClass1;
   }
}
```

## 2nd way

inside function definition, you can create **Synchronize Block**

example:

```
public static void setSomeClass(SomeClass = someClass1) {

     synchronized(this){

          if(isThreadStarted) {
            someClass = someClass1;
          }
    }
}
```

**2nd way is best approach**

Comment: In 2nd way if I am calling static method from different created object ,How it will be thread safe.

Comment: The does not make the class thread safe.  This only makes the setting of the someClas field thread safe through that one method.

Answer (score 1):

Two simple improvements you can make to make this class more threadsafe for the intended purpose are to make the someClass field volatile, and to use AtomicBoolean for the isThreadStarted field.

```
class Artifacts {
    private static AtomicBoolean isThreadStarted = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private volatile SomeClass someClass;
```

The volatile will ensure that any other thread that has a reference to an Artifact instance, does not cache the someClass instance.  The JVM will always retrieve the someClass field from one main source.  If volatile is not used, then other threads may cache someClass and changes it it may not be reflected across all the threads that are using it.

AtomicBoolean gives you volatile feature plus atomic operations, like check and set in the same operation.  Here is a excerpt from the Javadoc.

> A small toolkit of classes that support lock-free thread-safe programming on single variables. In essence, the classes in this package extend the notion of volatile values, fields, and array elements to those that also provide an atomic conditional update operation of the form:

Answer (score 1):

So, your main concern is that multiple threads will read and write the `someClass` field (and maybe the `isThreadStarted` field, as well).

I don't know what the `@ThreadSafe` annotation does, it's not part of Java Standard Edition 8.

The basic way to make that thread-safe is to use the `synchronized` keyword. Typically, you'd encapsulate access to your field in getter and setter methods and make them synchronized.

```
public class Test {
    private String someText;
    public synchronized String getSomeText() {
        return someText;
    }
    public synchronized void setSomeText(String someText) {
        this.someText = someText;
    }
}
```

But typically the multi-thread problems aren't tied to a single field.

If  different threads of your program use a (thread-shared) object, you run into the risk that one thread modifies two fields A and B (e.g. moves money from A to B by subtracting from A and adding to B), and in-between some other thread reads A and B (e.g. calculates the current amount of A plus B) and sees an inconsistent state (amount subtracted from A, but not yet added to B).

The classical solution is to ensure that of all these code sections where the instance is read or modified, only one at a time is allowed to run. And that's what `synchronized` does.